# HTML -- input/datalist events for executing search

Tags: html, reactjs

I have created a typeAhead component which is an input field with a datalist bound to it in a React app. I listen for the "onChange" event on the input field which fetches the matching typeAhead results and this works fine.

So now I am trying to add some listeners for executing the search which should happen when an option is selected from the dropdown or when "enter" key is pressed. I tried listening for the "onSelect" event but it never seems to get fired. And I'm not sure how to listen for the "enter" key event either.

```
render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input  type="text" id="searchfld" list="data" placeholder="Search..." onChange={getTypeAheadResults} />

                <datalist id="data" onChange= {executesearch} onSelect={executeSearch}></datalist>
            </div>
        );
}


const getTypeAheadResults= () => {
  //fires
}

const executesearch = () => {
  //does not fire
}
```

any help helps, thanks!

EDIT: Tharaka Wijebandara's answer solves the "enter" key issue. still trying to figure out how to listen for datalist selection.

just to reiterate -- when the user types something in the search field, I fetch the query results and add them to the datalist. This is working fine.

What I am trying to accomplish now is to call my executeSearch function when an option is selected from the datalist.

Comment: What does `datalist` component is returning? It's hard to debug without knowing

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to keyboard events: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  if(e.key == 'Enter'){
    //do something here
  }
}
<input type="text" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
```

But if the keypress isn't on an input, you could find a way to attach it to the body, or use `react-keydown`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown which will create a global listener when your component is mounted.

Comment: `datalist` is not a custom component. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: Oh *facepalm :)

Answer (score 1):

Use html `form` element instead of a `div` and use `onSubmit` event for listening "enter" key.

```
function render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSumbit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="searchfld"
        list="data"
        placeholder="Search..."
      />
      <datalist id="data"/>
    </form>
  );
}

const onSubmit = () => {
  //....
}
```